# Is there any package to drive excel applications using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

Except `win32ole` is there any other package to drive **excel,CSV** operations using Ruby?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to tell Excel to do it, or do you want to directly manipulate the spreadsheet?

Comment: There are at least two ways to deal with spreadsheets. You can have Ruby tell Excel to do things via OLE, or, you can open the spreadsheet in Ruby and load the CSV file and add it to the spreadsheet, without launching Excel.

Comment: I mentioned not to use `win32ole`. Looking for alternatives!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=excel

Choose what you like. If you specify what you want to do, maybe we can help you more. Until then, look at the gems on this list, they should help you :)

Comment: is there any to drive `.txt` files?

Comment: since the file extension doesn't matter, just open the txt file. it should contain plain text. `File.open("your_file","r").read` and you'll get the contents as a string.

Comment: Use `File.read('your_file')` instead of `File.open("your_file","r").read`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't vouch for it, but [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) exists. It's pretty old though.

[writeexcel](https://github.com/cxn03651/writeexcel) is newer, but I think it can only write to spreadsheets, not read.

**edit**

[spreadsheet](http://rubygems.org/gems/spreadsheet) also appears to be up to date, but it's only compatible with MS excel, according to the documentation.

Comment: `spreadsheet` or `writeexcel` contains more excel operations or both are same?

Comment: At a glance, it looks like `spreadsheet` does. You'll have to look into it more yourself though.

Comment: Definitely `writeexcel` would be a great option!